# Can I run an Android emulator from the command line without having to list all existing emulators

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-emulator, package.json

I'd like to create a script to add to my package.json file where I can run an existing Android emulator directly from the command line when I run `npm start`.

Right now, all the solutions I found tell me to use `emulator -list-avds` to list all existing emulators and then run `emulator -avd <AVD_NAME>` with the AVD_NAME manually picked from this list.

However, I want to write a script so that anyone who clones my application can simply run `npm start` to run the application without having to manually start the emulator themselves. Is this possible?

Comment: VS code with react native dev tools does this automatically

Comment: @VinXi I didn't know this, thanks! But I was hoping for another solution incase someone did not have the extension installed?

Comment: You can write a script which takes the output of emulator -list-avds then runs emulator -avd with first item in the output